# Keep web sessions

Tags: session, blackberry

I use an API that I first need to log in to and then I get access to view the nodes. These are the two urls that are used.

```
http://thewebpage.com/login.php?user=123&pass=123
http://thewebpage.com/get_nodes.php
```

The method im using to connect is the following

```
StreamConnection s = (StreamConnection)Connector.open(url);
InputStream input = s.openInputStream();

byte[] data = new byte[256];
int len = 0;
StringBuffer raw = new StringBuffer();

while( -1 != (len = input.read(data))) {
    raw.append(new String(data, 0, len));
}

response = raw.toString();
```

When I connect to `login.php` I get the response from the server that im logged in, but the problem is when I call `get_nodes.php` I get the response "please login" because the session isn't stored.

Is there any way to solve this so I can access the nodes?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it by saving the cookie data from the login and then put the cookie in the other http request like this

**Get cookie**

```
HttpConnection connection = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(loginUrl);
String cookieData = connection.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");
```

**Set cookie**

```
HttpConnection connection = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(nodeUrl);
connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookieData);
```